# VBA Excel Objects Out of Range All of the Sudden

Tags: excel, vba

I have reference to a number of tables in my workbook using vba. I have assigned them into listobjects based on the sheet index and then I load them into arrays.

Everything was working smoothly. I ran my code a number of times and no issue.

I then added a sheet of no consequence to the workbook and now each and every list object returns the error "***Subscript out of Range***" when they are being set.

Does adding a sheet usually break this? No current tab or table had a change to their names, they stayed exactly the same. I am at a loss.

Code Below

```
Sub ANALYSIS()
    
'DECLARE WORKSHEET OBJECTS
    Dim analysis_ws As Worksheet
    Dim model_ws As Worksheet
    Dim assumption_ws As Worksheet
    Dim headcount_ws As Worksheet
    Dim analysisD_ws As Worksheet
    
    'DECLARE INPUT OBJECTS
    Dim level_table As ListObject
    Dim scenario_table As ListObject
    Dim driver_table As ListObject
    Dim hdct_table As ListObject
    Dim type_table As ListObject
    
    'SET WORKSHEET OBJECTS
    Set analysis_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Set model_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
    Set assumption_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5)
    Set headcount_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(8)
    Set analysisD_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(13)
    
    'SET INPUT OBJECTS
    Set level_table = model_ws.ListObjects("TECH_LEVEL") '<- ERROR OCCURRs ON EACH ONE OF THESE
    Set scenario_table = model_ws.ListObjects("SCENARIO_MATRIX")
    Set driver_table = assumption_ws.ListObjects("UNITS")
    Set hdct_table = headcount_ws.ListObjects("HEADCOUNT")
    Set type_table = assumption_ws.ListObjects("UNIT_TYPE")

''' do stuff

end sub
```

[image]

[image: Sheet Index]

Comment: If you add a sheet, then double check that the numbering is correct, e.g. `... = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)` and it has the `SECNARIO_MATRIX` ListObject.  Instead, perhaps use sheet names, `model_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Model WS")`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes I checked and they are correct. All the indexes are the same and I added a picture of the sheet index and table name descriptions to confirm

Comment: You probably misinterpret the item indexes in `Sheets` collection. `Sheets(4)` is the fourth sheet visible in sheets register of Excel, not necessary the one with internally name "Sheet4". So do `Set model_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MODEL")` as suggested already.

Comment: @AxelRichter Your are correct. I am misinterpreting them. Strange though it worked at first. Taking your suggestion, the error is now fixed. Thank you